# encrypt password not working in codeigniter let me know where i'm wrong

Tags: codeigniter, encryption, phpmyadmin

controller

```
 $this->load->library('encrypt');
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('dpassword', 'Password','required|trim');
 $data=array('code goes here');
 $this->encrypt->encode($data);
```

but in phpmyadmin password won't get encrypted.if you have some solution for that.i did make changes in encryption key in config file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set an Encryption key and pass it as 2nd parameter of the encode function. For example:

```
 $this->load->library('encrypt');
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('dpassword', 'Password','required|trim');
 $data=array('code goes here');

 $key = 'super-secret-key'; //Your Encryption key

 $this->encrypt->encode($data,$key);
```

Just try this.. It may solve your problem

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: mcrypt_encrypt() expects parameter 3 to be string, array given

Filename: libraries/encrypt.php

Comment: i dont know where to find this file there is nothing in my libraries expect index.php file

Comment: You are passing an array into $this->encrypt->encode(). The encode() method takes a string.

Comment: may i know what data you are passing with $data

Comment: just test it with $data="some text";

Comment: i m passing $data in $this->encrypt->encode($data);

Comment: after var_dump($data) im getting all my db data

Comment: Ok. $data=$data=array('code goes here'); ; you are passing an array of values. just make a test with $data="some text" and check whether its working or not.

Comment: <?php error_reporting (0); ?> //add this at the top of the page

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE)  when i call $data="wow";